# Get LDAP group based on login username in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, active-directory, openldap

I need to retrieve the list of groups a user is in, using an LDAP query in Django. The use case is: a user fills in his LDAP login credentials, and Django will authenticate him and will also assign his **LDAP groups**.

The user login works flawlessly, but I cannot filter groups using `memberUid=%(user)s`. **I'm looking for the right method to pass the username as a filter argument to "groupfilter" property**. I tested the query with an LDAP application browser and seems to work properly.

- **OS:** Ubuntu 14.04 x64
- **Python version:** 2.7.6
- **Django version:**  (1, 6, 11, 'final', 0)

### RatticWeb LDAP configuration

I'm using [RatticWeb](https://github.com/tildaslash/RatticWeb) django application to manage users' passwords with the following local configuration (see also [Rattic repository wiki](https://github.com/tildaslash/RatticWeb/wiki/LDAP)):

<kbd>**conf/local.cfg**</kbd>

```
[ldap]
requirecert = True
# LDAP server details
uri = ldap://localhost:port
# Bind DN
binddn = cn=admin,dc=mydomain
bindpw = mypassword
# User parameters
userbase = ou=Users,dc=mydomain
userfilter = (uid=%(user)s)
#userfilter = (objectClass=person)
userfirstname = givenName
userlastname = sn
useldapgroups = True
# Set up the basic group parameters.
groupbase = ou=Groups,dc=mydomain
groupfilter = (&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid=%(user)s))  
grouptype = PosixGroupType
# How do I find staff
#staff = cn=staff,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
loglevel = DEBUG
```

This configuration file is read by **settings.py** ([source code](https://github.com/tildaslash/RatticWeb/blob/master/ratticweb/settings.py#L358)):

<kbd>**ratticweb/settings.py**</kbd>

```
 # Defaults to a bogus filter so that searching yields no errors in the log
 AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_FILTER = confget('ldap', 'groupfilter', '(objectClass=_fake)')
 AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(AUTH_LDAP_USER_BASE, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, AUTH_LDAP_USER_FILTER)
 AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_BASE, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_FILTER)
```

#### LOG

Now, I need to filter LDAP group passing the username parameter coming from user login form, and I tried using the same format of *userfilter* but the server give me back the following error:

```
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257325 2016] [:error] [pid 11280] 2016-01-13 16:51:24,256 [ERROR] Caught Exception while authenticating myusername
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257438 2016] [:error] [pid 11280] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257478 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 323, in authenticate
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257515 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]     self._get_or_create_user()
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257550 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 539, in _get_or_create_user
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257586 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]     self._mirror_groups()
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257620 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 638, in _mirror_groups
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257697 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]     group_names = self._get_groups().get_group_names()
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257734 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 755, in get_group_names
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257770 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]     group_infos = self._get_group_infos()
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257804 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap/backend.py", line 803, in _get_group_infos
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257835 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]     self._group_search)
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257864 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap/config.py", line 374, in user_groups
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257893 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]     groups = search.execute(ldap_user.connection)
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257928 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap/config.py", line 150, in execute
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257957 2016] [:error] [pid 11280]     filterstr = self.filterstr % filterargs
[Wed Jan 13 16:51:24.257990 2016] [:error] [pid 11280] TypeError: format requires a mapping
```

### EDIT: Cause of the error

The constructor of `LDAPSearch` populates its attributes as follows:

```
self.base_dn = 'groupbase = ou=Groups,dc=mydomain'
self.scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
self.filterstr = '(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid=%(user)s))'
```

<kbd>/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_auth_ldap/config.py #150</kbd>

```
def execute(self, connection, filterargs=()):
    """
    Executes the search on the given connection (an LDAPObject). filterargs
    is an object that will be used for expansion of the filter string.

    The python-ldap library returns utf8-encoded strings. For the sake of
    sanity, this method will decode all result strings and return them as
    Unicode.
    """
    try:
        filterstr = self.filterstr % filterargs
        results = connection.search_s(self.base_dn.encode('utf-8'),
                                      self.scope,
                                      filterstr.encode('utf-8'))
    except ldap.LDAPError, e:
        results = []
        logger.error(u"search_s('%s', %d, '%s') raised %s" %
                     (self.base_dn, self.scope, filterstr, pprint.pformat(e)))

    return self._process_results(results)
```

Comment: This error is given by the absence, I prsume, of the right filterargs definition of `user`. This (https://github.com/almet/django-auth-ldap/blob/master/django_auth_ldap/config.py#L155) is the line of code that's generating the exception:

    `filterstr = self.filterstr % filterargs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I've found the solution:

<kbd>**conf/local.cfg**</kbd>

```
[ldap]
....
# Set up the basic group parameters.
groupbase = ou=Groups,dc=mydomain
groupfilter = (objectClass=posixGroup)  
grouptype = PosixGroupType
...
```

The key factor is the use of the groupType `PosixGroupType`, because the query on Groups would be filtered on the memberUid parameter by Django Auth LDAP (observe the else part of the `user_groups` function:

```
class PosixGroupType(LDAPGroupType):
  """
  An LDAPGroupType subclass that handles groups of class posixGroup.
  """
  def user_groups(self, ldap_user, group_search):
    """
    Searches for any group that is either the user's primary or contains the
    user as a member.
    """
    groups = []

    try:
        user_uid = ldap_user.attrs['uid'][0]

        if 'gidNumber' in ldap_user.attrs:
            user_gid = ldap_user.attrs['gidNumber'][0]
            filterstr = u'(|(gidNumber=%s)(memberUid=%s))' % (
                self.ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars(user_gid),
                self.ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars(user_uid)
            )
        else:
            filterstr = u'(memberUid=%s)' % (
                self.ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars(user_uid),
            )

        search = group_search.search_with_additional_term_string(filterstr)
        groups = search.execute(ldap_user.connection)
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        pass

    return groups
```